# IndexError: list index out of range при использовании регулярок

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\alibPars\main.py", line 34, in <module>
price = re.findall(r'\d+', all_data[2])
                           ~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Выбивает такую ошибку.
Код:

```
for page in booksPage:
soup = get_soup(page)
book = soup.find_all('p')
count = 0
for item in book:
    count += 1
    if 4 <= count <= 63:
        name = item.find('b').text.strip()
        all_data = [c.strip() for c in item if c.name is None and c.strip() != '']
        price = ''
        if len(all_data) >= 1:
            price = re.findall(r'\d+', all_data[2])
        date = ''
        if len(re.findall(r'\d{4}[-]\d{4}[г][.]', all_data[0])) != 0:
            date = re.findall(r'\d{4}[-]\d{4}[г][.]', all_data[0])
        elif len(re.findall(r'[\[]\d{4}[]][г][.]', all_data[0])) != 0:
            date = re.findall(r'[\[]\d{4}[]][г][.]', all_data[0])
        else:
            date = re.findall(r'\d{4}[г][.]', all_data[0])
```

И так с каждой переменной в которой есть регулярка. Данные берутся при парсинге со страницы, переменные не пустые, в них есть данные.

upd: начало выбивать новую ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\alibPars\main.py", line 41, in <module>
if len(re.findall(r'\d{4}[-]\d{4}[г][.]', all_data[0])) != 0:
                                          ~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Ну, не вижу в коде инициализации переменной item. Если его нет, то инициализируйте и ошибка исчезнет.

Comment: item в цикле (for item in book:), этот код заключен внутри этого цикла

Comment: добавил код в вопрос

Comment: Регулярки тут совершенно не при чем. Если в списке меньше элементов, чем индекс, по котопуму идёт обращение, то будет такая ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно проверить длину списка, перед использованием, чтобы не было ошибки

```
if len(all_data)>=3:
        price = re.findall(r'\d+', all_data[2])
```

Comment: Это помогло решить данную проблему, но вылезла новая

Comment: Если all_data[0]  index out of range, значит этот список пустой, и нужно смотреть, что с данными. Но проверки не помешают, условия проверок зависят от данных. Это не правильно `if len(re.findall(r'\d{4}[-]\d{4}[г][.]', all_data[0])) != 0:`  проверять длину списка`if not len(all_data):`